# How can I drop shadow background on Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, shapes

I want to add a background behind the button. I want to create an opaque shape from white color for this background.. I did this with a gradient, but I couldn't. I want to create a soft shape.. I want a white shape like in the picture

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <gradient
       android:angle="270"
       android:dither="false"
       android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:startColor="#CCFFFFFF" />
   <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" // here
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to google about drop shadow in android

Comment: Since I couldn't find anything like what I was looking for, I asked here anyway.

Comment: What is the question? What is your desired result?

Comment: @Darkman I want a white shape like in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86itL.png

Comment: @test721 Shadow will overlap text?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FrameLayout as root layout, and use an ImageView anchored to the bottom of the screen:

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/id_framelayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YourActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:src="@drawable/shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
           
            < IF YOU WANT, YOU CAN INSERT HERE YOUR BUTTON >

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The shadow should be defined on `res/drawable/shadow.xml` as follows:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#88FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="linear">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

Comment: sorry but the bottom parts are still very opaque so the text at the bottom is visible

Comment: You should set the center color in order to tune the gradient, I edited my answer using a more opaque color. Anyway, if you want to have a white area at the bottom of the gradient (following the new image you posted with your last edit, where you want to place the green botton), you should simply add a layout with white background containing your button below the gradient. A vertical LinearLayout should be fine to wrap gradient and button.

Comment: I modified my answer wrapping the gradient into a Layout, as I described in the previous comment.

Comment: I checked your edit but there is a problem; For the 200dp high area, the finish line is very clear...
 I want it to end softer, like a shadow, it's not very nice if it suddenly ends so sharply

Comment: Please do a bit of work trying to set the value of the widgets to obtain the effect you want. The values I put are only an example to show widgets and layout hierarchy. I suggest to work on centerColor and layout_heights. If you cannot obtain the result using a single gradient, you could put two or more of them into LinearLayout in order to have a better control of shade transition.